# Не работает условие while

Tags: python, while, float

Вот так работает...

```
price_list=[]

user_input=float(input('Please enter amount"s->'))
price_list.append(user_input)

while user_input!=000:
        user_input=float(input('Please enter amount"s->'))
        price_list.append(user_input)
price_list.remove(000)
full_sum=sum(price_list)
sum_cents=(full_sum*100)/5
if sum_cents<2.5:
        total=round(full_sum-0.05)
        print('Total Price',total)
elif sum_cents>2.5:
        total=round(full_sum+0.05)
        print('Total Price',total)
```

А вот так нет....

```
price_list=[]

user_input=float(input('Please enter amount"s->'))
price_list.append(user_input)

while user_input!='':
        user_input=float(input('Please enter amount"s->'))
        price_list.append(user_input)
price_list.remove('')
full_sum=sum(price_list)
sum_cents=(full_sum*100)/5
if sum_cents<2.5:
        total=round(full_sum-0.05)
        print('Total Price',total)
elif sum_cents>2.5:
        total=round(full_sum+0.05)
        print('Total Price',total)
```

То есть по сути не работает выход из цикла по пробелу от пользователя, но в силу своих скудных познаний я не могу понять почему.
ведь здесь :

```
while user_input!=''
```

Нет никаких проверок.
Дебагер показывает ошибку здесь:

```
while user_input!='':
(на этой строке)  user_input=float(input('Please enter amount"s->'))
```

Возникло исключение: ValueError
could not convert string to float: ''

И как правильно решить или обойти эту проблему? Как я не пытался, не получается. Спасибо

Comment: Ну так пробел вы не можете в float определить, это строка вот он и ошибку показывает. Написано же) Вам лучше отдельно конвертировать пользовательский ввод, а перед этим проверять равен ли символу пробела

Comment: Да, согласен. Но как сделать правильно выход по пробелу(по сути по пустой строке) от пользователя ? Спасибо

Comment: Пустая строка и пробел -  это не одно и тоже! Наберите ''==' ' и посмотрите получаемое значение этого логического оператора.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наверное вы можете сделать так:

```
price_list=[]

while (text := input('Please enter amount"s->')) and text != ' ':
    price_list.append(float(text))

full_sum = sum(price_list)
sum_cents = (full_sum * 100) / 5
total = 0

if sum_cents < 2.5:
    total = round(full_sum-0.05)
elif sum_cents > 2.5:
    total = round(full_sum+0.05)

print('Total Price', total)
```

Comment: Интересное решение, я даже не знал что так можно сделать. Спасибо!

Comment: Работает для python 3.8+